# Windows 8.1 x64 setup error: could not configure windows

Tags: windows, installation, windows-8.1

I am trying to install Windows 8.1 and I get the following error after first reboot during setup:

> Windows setup could not configure Windows to run on this computer's hardware

I have the following specs:

- CPU: AMD Phenom II X6 1090T 3.2 GHz
- Motherboard: Gigabyte Technology GA-890GPA-UD3H Rev: 2101
- BIOS: Award/Modular BIOS v6.00PG

Anybody know how I can get more information about this cryptic error? (any debug-verbose mode on Windows setup?)

Comment: upload the logs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824819.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in my case was to unplug all other hard disk drives.
Specifically i had extra internals and externals hard disk drives pluged in on my initial attempt to install windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Source:
[microsoft.com](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-requirements)

Make sure you have enough RAM, and Hard Disk Space, and other HW requirements

> Windows 8.1 If you want to run Windows 8.1 on your PC, here's what it
>   takes:
>
> Processor: 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster with support for PAE, NX, and
>   SSE2 (more info)
>
> RAM: 1 gigabyte (GB) (32-bit) or 2 GB (64-bit)
>
> Hard disk space: 16 GB (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
>
> Graphics card: Microsoft DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM driver